# Do questions about vehicles security belong here?

Tags: discussion

As in questions about cars doors, locks and keys.

Answer (score 9):

In short yes.

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and
>   their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications
>   other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or
>   engine accessories.

See the [help center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes they do but....**

I'm reluctant to get too detailed.

I feel like we get trolled by theives from time to time trying to find ways to defeat security systems.

I'm reluctant to give full details and typically answer with, get your ID, your title and VIN...goto the dealer and have a new key made...or whattever.

I never feel 100% about those questions and they make me nervous.  I don't want to contribute to the knowledge base of someone that may be trying to do harm so most of the time I avoid a direct answer.

Comment: Agreed. Some Fora specifically ban security questions for exactly that reason. I'd say that questions about maintaining the security side are allowed, but not those regarding circumventing it

Comment: The Ford Ranger question yesterday was a good example... I went for 'take it to the dealer'

Comment: Modern automobile security system's aren't like early 80's to mid 90's security systems and require encoded messages between the antitheft module and the PCM. It would probably require more effort and time on the part of the thief to circumvent this. If you look at modern aftermarket remote starts they require a transponder (on keyless start) be left in the vehicle to even start the engine.